# MySQL 3D "Flood Fill" Implementation

Tags: mysql, flood-fill

I have a MySQL table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `np_voxels` (
  `world` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  `x` INT NOT NULL,
  `y` INT NOT NULL,
  `z` INT NOT NULL,
  `value` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `property_id` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`world`, `x`, `y`, `z`) ,
  INDEX `np_fk_voxels_properties_idx` (`property_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `np_fk_voxels_properties`
    FOREIGN KEY (`property_id`)
    REFERENCES `np_properties` (`property_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I want two select queries that can find all connected voxels given a starting voxel that match a specific condition. One `WHERE world = @world AND value > @minvalue AND property_id IS NULL` and the other `WHERE world = @world AND property_id = @property_id`.
The flood fill algorithm used should be fast enough to where it doesn't cause noticeable lag (this will be used on a game server). There should also be a bounding box centered on the starting voxel that the query cannot go out of. On the `y` axis, this would go from `0` to `@ymax`. The default for this will be `31`. For the `x` and `z` axis, This should extend out `@hdistance` from the starting `x` or `z`.

**Input**

- `@world`
- `@startx`
- `@starty`
- `@startz`
- `@minvalue` or `@property_id` (Depends what the program is looking for.)
- `@hdistance` Default: `13`
- `@ymax` Default: `31`

I've searched on Google, and haven't found an existing implementation in MySQL. I don't understand how the faster and more complicated flood fill algorithms work to attempt to write this on my own.

Comment: Fast flood-fill should NOT be implemented in SQL. You can load all needed data to your application to proper structures (probably some graph representation or 3d array depending on the density of your data) and run the stack/queue or any other implementation you can write in the programming language at hand. Flood-fill is by definition recursive (even when it is often implemented by loops) and SQL is not good at recursion nor with loops.

Comment: @jkavalik Good point. I originally thought that it would be faster if mysql did that kind of processing. Can you repost this as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast flood-fill should NOT be implemented in SQL. You can load all the needed data to your application to proper structures (probably some graph representation or 3d array depending on the density of your data) and run the stack/queue or any other implementation you can write in the programming language at hand. Flood-fill is by definition recursive (even when it is often implemented by loops) and SQL is not good at recursion nor with loops.

But there is something which might be used in mysql, even when it is not a normal SQL solution. There is a special engine to handle graphs - [OQGRAPH](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/oqgraph-examples/). It is available in MariaDB and might be installable to MySQL probably.

It supports effective storage of combinatorial graphs of which a grid is just a special case and it can compute shortest paths and reachability. From the examples page it knows `dijkstras` and `breadth_first` - the latter should be usable as a flood fill implementation.

Depending on your needs you should be able to write something more performant because you can tailor it to your specific nee. But if you want to experiment and compare more implementation, you can try it.